# Webots - Adding animatedGeometry to my tracked robot gives strange shapes for the belt containing the wheels

Tags: webots

Dears
Thanks in advance

If anybody can point me to the problem
I've made a tracked robot , and added the left track with 7 wheels, defined the bounding Objects to include the wheels, but I get a strange shape as shown below :

[image]

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I knew the exact problem so I'm posting the answer below :
based on the documentation for defining the tracked wheels in webots : https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/track?tab-language=python

> Each wheel contains the information about its center position, its
> radius and if it is inside or outside the belt. By convention the
> wheels are all aligned on a plane perpendicular to the Track node's
> z-axis and have to be defined in clockwise order starting from the one
> with the smallest x-axis position component.

[image]